# how to calculate the sentiment score for the dataframe using SpacyTextBlob?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy-3

I am finding sentiment scores for reviews using SpacyTextblob. I can able to calculate the polarity and subjectivity score for individual text but unable to calculate for the column

My data frame called 'data' which has reviews called reviews.text column

```
import spacy
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe("spacytextblob")
doc = nlp(data['reviews.text'][0])

print('Polarity:', doc._.polarity)
print('Sujectivity:', doc._.subjectivity)
```

The above code is working for each review separately and I can calculate the polarity and subjectivity. However, I cannot ale to calculate for the entire column

```
polarity = lambda x: nlp(x)._.polarity
subjectivity = lambda x: nlp(x)._.subjectivity
data['polarity'] = data['reviews.text'].apply(polarity)
df['subjectivity'] = data['reviews.text'].apply(subjectivity)
```

The above code is not working, can anyone tell me how to calculate it?